# How do I write a regex in PHP to remove special characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty new to PHP, and I noticed there are many different ways of handling regular expressions.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
$replace = array(" ",".",",","'","@");
$newString = str_replace($replace,"_",$join);

$join = "the original string i'm parsing through";
```

I want to remove everything which isn't a-z, A-Z, or 0-9. I'm looking for a reverse function of the above. A pseudocode way to write it would be

> If characters in $join are not equal to a-z,A-Z,0-9
>   then change characters in `$join` to `"_"`

Answer (score 46):

```
$newString = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $join);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hi antennen, thanks for the reply! is this case sensitive, will it except capitals? Thanks, Ben.

Comment: That's what the 'i' at the end is for - case insensitive.

Comment: note that this regex will replace consecutive occurrences of non-alphanumeric characters with a single _. Thus '@@@' would be replaced with '_' not '___'. Remove the + if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: Good thing you pointed that out, I normally throw away characters using the same method. The plus is just old habit. Edited since it didn't replicate OP's stated behavoir.

Comment: Thanks mark, The addition character is actually quite useful for what i am trying to achieve :)

Comment: Thanks antennen, mark! if i wanted to allow certain characters along with the a-z0-9 eg. a backwards slash, how would i do this? sorry to ask a question in the comments section.

Comment: A backward slash is a bit special. IIRC it'd be '/[^a-z0-9\\\\\]/i'

Answer (score 13):

The regular expression for anything which isn't a-z, A-Z, 0-9 is:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', "_", $join);
```

This is known as a [Negated Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is this:

```
preg_replace('/\W/', '_', $join);
```

\W is the non-word character group.  A word character is a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _.  \W matches everything not previously mentioned*.

Edit: preg uses Perl's regular expressions, documented in the [perlman perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) document.

*Edit 2: This assumes a C or one of the English locales.  Other locales may have accented letters in the word character class.  The Unicode locales will only consider characters below code point 128 to be characters.

Comment: Due to localization it might contain other characters than a-z though.

Comment: Actually, that's a good point.  I'm not sure how PCRE or PHP particularly handles that.  I'll see if I can find any docs about it.

Comment: I found this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php
Scroll down to \W.

Comment: This was perfect - especially for &amp; type characters - not sure about returns etc