# Php regular expression failed

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I am trying to write a regex that will only allow text uppercase and lower.  I had no idea how to write any regex so I found a post on Stack

[How do I write a regex in PHP to remove special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745282/how-do-i-write-a-regex-in-php-to-remove-special-characters)

With a link to a place to learn.  The tut is fantastic so do read if yuo have trouble with regex.

```
if( preg_match('/^([A-Za-z\s]+)&/', $pagename) ) {
 //do stuff
 } 
 else  
 {echo"no special char or num";}
```

How ever it fails.  If I type for example

New Web Page

it should allow this but it fails.

Comment: fyi \s matches for a "whitespace" character (eg: a space, tab, etc.). If you really want to only match letters, you need to remove that.  Also, you can shorten the regex by using the i modifier.

Comment: are you sure the $pagename contains the correct value that you are parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is the right sign for ends with not `&`

it should be `/^([A-Za-z\s]+)$/`

Answer (score 1):

`I am trying to write a regex that will only allow text uppercase and lower.` All you need is

```
 '/^([A-Z]+)$/i'
            ^
            |-------- Note used $ instead of &
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the **round** brackets, and replace & with $ (end of string).

Comment: He needs the brackets to show that a-z and A-Z are character sets

Comment: I suspect he means the parentheses rather than the brackets - technically the parentheses are unnecessary unless you want to create/store a sub-pattern.

Comment: `()`, `[]`, `{}` - are these A) (round) brackets, square brackets, curly brackets, or B) parens, brackets, braces? :-)

Comment: OP's looking for a true or false, so he needs the square brackets but not the round ones so `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/` would do exactly what he wants.

Comment: Yes,  brackets means (), should've been clearer I meant those and not the Square brackets []!