# How to replace multiple values in a PHP variable like sanitizing it

Tags: php

I am completely new to PHP and to prevent from any attack and to store proper values in a variable I am trying to sanitize, trim for spaces and remove any illegal character. I have a variable

```
$value = "this, <script></script>, 's 18in,";
```

The above variable consists many unwanted characters like `,` `blank space`, `<> tags`.

What I want to do is I want to remove all the invalid characters from the string and make it a pure form string with only have alphabets or numbers like

```
$value = "thiss18in"; <= after sanitization
```

Can anyone help me with this logic?

Comment: Can you post code of what you have already tried?

Comment: better to use PHP regular expression. Also PHP strip_tags will remove all tags but leave special characters that you can save in DB and show by real escape string and htmlspecialchars respectively (based on your needs). Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745282/how-do-i-write-a-regex-in-php-to-remove-special-characters

Comment: i just used this trim function only `$value = trim("this, <script></script>, 's 18in,");` as i am completely new to PHP i am having problem to achieve it

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer you can find. [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you can use this Logic:

```
$value = "this, <script></script>, 's 18in,";
$newString = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $value));
```

The `preg_replace` will replace all the invalid characters and only give u a pure formatted string of character and number if there are any spaces in the string the `trim` function will take care of it.

I have taken a reference from this question and editing according to what you wanted. Link => [How do I write a regex in PHP to remove special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745282/how-do-i-write-a-regex-in-php-to-remove-special-characters)

Comment: Thanks @Akshay Shrivastav your reference provided worked perfectly for me and thanks for the modified code. That was what i wanted.

Comment: +1 from me for giving the proper credit. On a side note: The `trim()` function is not needed here. The regex will replace spaces with nothing just as well :)

Comment: @icecub uum i just gave it for additional precaution  and thanks for the vote :)

Comment: Yes. But your code doesn't actually work. Your regex doesn't replace alphanumeric characters. So `<script></script>` will turn into `scriptscript` instead of completely removing the tags

Comment: please read the question, the asker didn't mention about that one. According to which i have provided the code.

Comment: `<> tags` <-- clearly referencing tags. Not `greater than or lesser than` signs

Comment: Not picking on you or anything m8. Just giving you the opportunity to improve your answer. A simple adeption with `strip_tags()` will solve the problem :)

Comment: Also please, read the question again. `$value = "thiss18in"; <= after sanitization` I don't see the words script in there. Do you?

Comment: yes u have a valid point  but what can i do bro  the asker himself marked it

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = "this, <script></script>, 's 18in,";
$value = strip_tags($value);
$newString = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $value);
echo $newString;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DDHaG)

Reference : [How do I write a regex in PHP to remove special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745282/how-do-i-write-a-regex-in-php-to-remove-special-characters)

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer in my opinion, since it actually works. (Unlike the accepted answer) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the  [php filter extension](http://php.net/book.filter) in modern php versions.

Or try to combine the functions [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities), [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) and [mysqli-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

I think this is the most complete answer you can find. [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Comment: I think you should not reference to functions that have been deprecated for more than 3 years. I've replaced `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` for you.